Generating a JWT for calling API after logging in with Identity Aware Proxy
I have 2 apps deployed to Cloud Run, the first is Nginx serving up a React app and the other is a FastAPI API, with Identity Aware Proxy on both of the load balancers set up to check against Identity Platform.
We have an Authentication URL running gcr.io/gcip-iap/authui which I understand to be this bit of the iap-gcip-web-toolkit project.
I can generate a valid JWT to use on the backend LB with
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "test@mydomain.com", "SomePassword")
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
      console.log(token)
    })
  })

But that is side-stepping the fact I'm already authed and logging in again.
How can I get a user (so I can call getIdToken) given that I'm logged in already? (I see GCP_IAP_UID and __Host-GCP_IAP_AUTH_TOKEN_XXXXXXXXXX in my cookies and can load the JS/HTML for the React app)

You don’t need to call signInWithEmailAndPassword again if you’re already authenticated. Firebase should automatically manage the session for you. You can check if the user is logged in by using auth.currentUser, and then call getIdToken() directly.
const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

if (user) {
  user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
    console.log(token); // Use this token for your backend requests
  });
} else {
  console.log("User not authenticated");
}

If auth.currentUser is null, make sure Firebase is initialized correctly and check if the session is being persisted. Hope this works for you.

This does not work unfortunately (it was the first thing I tried, I should have said)

Assuming you have something like this implemented and still cannot receive the user, hence the token:
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, retrieve the ID token
    user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
      console.log("ID Token:", token);
      // Use the token as needed
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error retrieving ID token:", error);
    });
  } else {
    // No user is signed in, handle accordingly
    console.log("No user signed in");
  }
});

As a workaround, I believe you can re-authenticate automatically to grab a user right after using your existing token in a cookie:
import { getAuth, signInWithCredential, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const token = getCookie('__Host-GCP_IAP_AUTH_TOKEN_XXXXXXXXXX'); // Retrieve the token from the cookie

if (token) {
  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
  signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log("User reauthenticated:", user);
      return user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((idToken) => {
      console.log("ID Token:", idToken);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error reauthenticating:", error);
    });
} else {
  console.error("IAP token not found");
}


thanks for this but I think the cookie actually isnt valid there, I get: "Error reauthenticating: FirebaseError: Firebase: Unable to parse Google id_token". They refer to the cookie as "opaque" so I dont think you can do anything with it whereas I think if you already had a jwt you could use it there
